# (Titanium mobile, Android) activeTab.open() new window is not preserving tabs

Tags: javascript, android, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-mobile

I am new and I saw similar questions but quite old and without solution. All I want is to open new window inside activeTab and preserve the tab group. Unfortunately my code opens new window but does not keep the tabs, the window is just full screen.
I would greatly appreciate if someone could confirm if what I want to achieve is possible at all. Maybe with views somehow... Once again it should work for android. Here is the code:

```
// this sets the background color of the master UIView (when there are no windows/tab groups on it)
Titanium.UI.setBackgroundColor('#000');

// create tab group
var tabGroup = Titanium.UI.createTabGroup();

//
// create base UI tab and root window
//
var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
    title:'Tab 1',
    backgroundColor:'#fff'
});
var tab1 = Titanium.UI.createTab({  
    icon:'KS_nav_views.png',
    title:'Tab 1',
    window:win1
});


//
// create controls tab and root window
//
var win2 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
    title:'Tab 2',
    backgroundColor:'#fff'
});
var tab2 = Titanium.UI.createTab({  
    icon:'KS_nav_ui.png',
    title:'Tab 2',
    window:win2
});

var label2 = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    color:'#999',
    text:'I am Window 2',
    font:{fontSize:20,fontFamily:'Helvetica Neue'},
    textAlign:'center',
    width:'auto'
});

win2.add(label2);


var data = [
    {title:"Sample 1",color:'black',hasChild:true,font:{fontSize:16,fontWeight:'bold'}},
    {title:"Sample 2",color:'black',hasChild:true,font:{fontSize:16,fontWeight:'bold'}}
    ];
var table = Titanium.UI.createTableView({
    data:data,
    separatorColor: '#ccc',
    backgroundColor:'#fff'
    });
win1.add(table);

// create table view event listener
table.addEventListener('click', function(e)
{
        var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
            url:'windows/main.js'       
        });

        // this simply opens the new created window but full screen and without original tab group.

         tabGroup.activeTab.open(win,{animated:true});


});

//
//  add tabs
//
tabGroup.addTab(tab1);  
tabGroup.addTab(tab2);  


// open tab group
tabGroup.open();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create navigation group for each tab windows.
For example

```
//Here's the first window...
var first = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor:"#fff",
    title:"My App"
});
```

Next, we’ll create a NavigationGroup. This is an iPhone-only component that controls a stack of windows (reference doc) – we’ll pass it our first window to use as its initially viewable window:

```
    //Here's the nav group that will hold them both...
    var firstnavGroup = Ti.UI.iPhone.createNavigationGroup({
        window:first
    });




    //This is the main window of the application
    var mainfirst = Ti.UI.createWindow();
    mainfirst.add(firstnavGroup);
```

then assing this mainfirst window to tab.
Repeat this prosess for all tabs

Now when you need to open new window then you have to write

```
var second = Ti.UI.createWindow({
  background:"#fff",
  title:"Child Window"
});

  firstnavGroup.open(second);
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: question is for Android, not iPhone. Android does not have navgroups

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to do that on android:

http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/145471/application-with-strange-navigation-how-to-implement-it#answer-252500

here you can find a demo of my solution...

http://sharesend.com/kbkasavo

hope this helps